# TCL : to print the remaining characters/string once the particular string is matched

Tags: tcl

I have a variable as in,

```
set recA "Description        : 10/100/Gig-Ethernet-TX-test
Interface          : 1/1/18                     Oper Speed       : N/A
Link-level         : Ethernet                   Config Speed     : 1 Gbps
Admin State        : down                       Oper Duplex      : N/A
Oper State         : down                       Config Duplex    : full"
```

If i give my input as "Description" , i need print the value as "10/100/Gig-Ethernet-TX-test"

Similarly, if my input is "Config Speed" , i need to print the values as "1 Gbps"

i tried like this but did not get the output properly for "Config Speed"

```
set lines [split $recA \n]
set index [lsearch -regexp $lines "Description"]
set match [lrange $lines [expr $index] [expr $index]]
set b [lindex [lindex [split [join $match " "] ":"] 1] 0]
puts $b
```

for "Description" i get the output as 10/100/Gig-Ethernet-TX-test

for "Config Speed" , i get the output as "Ethernet" instead of "1 Gbps"

Can someone help ?

Answer (score 2):

That's quite a messy format to handle as it is entirely optimised for people and not for computers. We can tidy it up, but only by being a bit tricky: we need to use newlines and *multi-space sequences* as basic separators.

```
# How to split by regular expression
set fields [split [regsub -all {[ ]{2,}|\n} $recA "\u0100"] "\u0100"]

# Clean the values up
set mapping [lmap f $fields {string trim $f " :"}]

# OK, now we have a dictionary and can just look things up in it
puts [dict get $mapping "Description"];   # >>> 10/100/Gig-Ethernet-TX-test
puts [dict get $mapping "Config Speed"];  # >>> 1 Gbps
```

Comment: The `\u0100` is just a unicode character very unlikely to come up in the real data. There's masses of other ones you could choose.

Comment: Nice approach -- whittling away at the input until a dictionary appears.

Comment: i get an error like this. Do i need to do dict create ?                    key "Config Speed" not known in dictionary
    while executing
"dict get $mapping "Config Speed""
    invoked from within
"puts [dict get $mapping "Config Speed"]"

Comment: Well, it worked for me with exactly the sample data you provided.